# Configuring Misfire Handling at Config File Level

Tags: quartz.net

Is there a way to configure the misfire handling for all triggers in a Quartz.Net scheduler at the quartz.config file level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. You must keep in mind that available misfire handling policies are trigger type specific. You can define them on trigger basis if you are using the job scheduling XML file.